# wxPython: Making a fixed-height panel

Tags: python, layout, wxpython, widget

I have a wx.Frame, in which I have a vertical BoxSizer with two items, a TextCtrl and a custom widget. I want the custom widget to have a fixed pixel height, while the TextCtrl will expand normally to fill the window. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it.

When creating the widget, use a size of `(-1,100)`, where "`100`" is the height you want. Apparently the "`-1`" is a sort of "None" in this context.

When adding the widget to the sizer, use a proportion of 0, like this:
`self.sizer.Add(self.timeline,0,wx.EXPAND)`